# Two different results of NIntegrate in a unit cube

Tags: numerical-integration

The problem to solve is as follows. In a unit cube $\left(x,y,z\right) = (0,1)^2$ find a volume of a shape produced by following inequlity:
$$2 x^2 + y (1 + z) + x (z-y-2)<0$$

Eventually, I need an exact result. However, my approach seems to be wrong for some reason I don't see. If I write

```
NIntegrate[If[2 x^2 + y (1 + z) + x (-2 - y + z) < 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

I get $0.205431$. On the other hand, if I solve for $z$ in the inequality, i.e.

$$z < \frac{(1-x) (2 x-y)}{x+y}$$

and treat the problem as a double integral, i.e.

```
NIntegrate[If[0 < ((1 - x) (2 x - y))/(x + y) < 1, ((1 - x) (2 x - y))/(x + y), 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

I get the result $0.181523$.

Why these results are different? I would be very greatful.

Comment: How is it possible? Since the coefficient by $z$ is $(x+y)$, which is allways positive in the unit square so we can divide by it in the inequality?

Comment: Your first sentence is very confusing! What is "unit cube $(x,y,z)=(0,1)^2$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use `Boole` instead of `If` here:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[2 x^2 + y (1 + z) + x (-2 - y + z) < 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,1}, {z, 0,1}]
(*0.205431*)
```

Beneath the inequality `z< …` don't forget to require `0<z<1`! This gives

```
NIntegrate[Boole[0 < z < 1], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z,0, -(((-1 + x) (2 x - y))/(x +y))}]
 (*0.205431*)
```

The reduction of the second integral in your question to a double integral is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

By using a [region](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html) you can abstract the details of the integration away:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[2 x^2 + y (1 + z) + x (-2 - y + z) < 0,
                   {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];

RegionMeasure[R, 3] // FullSimplify
(*    3/2 + Log[(81 Sqrt[3])/512]    *)

% // N
(*    0.205431    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you solve $z$ by $x$ and $y$,then the integral should separate into three parts.

```
Reduce[2 x^2 + y (1 + z) + x (-2 - y + z) < 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 
  0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, z]
```

```
(0 < x <= 1/
    2 && ((0 <= y < (-x + 2 x^2)/(-2 + x) && 
       0 <= z <= 1) || (y == (-x + 2 x^2)/(-2 + x) && 
       0 <= z < 1) || ((-x + 2 x^2)/(-2 + x) < y < 2 x && 
       0 <= z < (2 x - 2 x^2 - y + x y)/(x + y)))) || (1/2 < x < 1 && 
   0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z < (2 x - 2 x^2 - y + x y)/(x + y))
```

So we need to integral the three parts respectively.

```
{NIntegrate[(-x + 2 x^2)/(-2 + x), {x, 0, 1/2}, {z, 0, 1}], 
 NIntegrate[(2 x - 2 x^2 - y + x y)/(
  x + y), {x, 0, 1/2}, {y, (-x + 2 x^2)/(-2 + x), 2 x}], 
 NIntegrate[(2 x - 2 x^2 - y + x y)/(x + y), {x, 1/2, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}
% // Total
```

```
{0.0239076, 0.0788078, 0.102715}
0.205431
```